# Constrained optimization where the choice is a function over an interval

Tags: functions, optimization, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I would like to solve a constrained optimization problem where the choice is a function over an interval rather than a finite number of variables or a sequence. The problem is given by:

$\max_{[x(i)]_{i=0}^1} \int_{i=0}^1 f(x(i))di$ subject to $\int_{i=0}^1 x(i)di = X$

where $x(i) > 0, \forall i \in [0,1]$, and $f:\mathbb{R}^{++}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable, strictly increasing and strictly concave function, i.e. $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) < 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. An example would be $f(x) = \ln(x)$.

I intuitively know that a solution is $x(i) = X, \forall i \in [0,1]$. I also can see that $x(i) = X$ must be true almost everywhere for any solution. Mimicking the heuristics of constrained optimization problems where the choice is over a countable number of points, I would assign a multiplier $\lambda$ to the constraint, and then obtain a candidate solution by:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x(i)}\left(f(x(i))\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x(i)} \left(-\lambda x(i)\right) = 0, \forall i \in [0,1]$

$f'(x(i)) = \lambda, \forall i \in [0,1]$

$x(i) = x(j) \equiv x, \forall i,j \in [0,1]$

$\int_{i=0}^1 xdi = X \Rightarrow x = X = x(i), \forall i \in [0,1]$

However, I do not know how to prove this, or which theorem to invoke. If the choice variable was a sequence, I would use Karush-Kuhn-Tucker. Which theorem should I use when the choice is a function over an interval rather than a sequence? What is the general name for this type of constrained optimization problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is a good idea to frame the question in terms of some 'well known' space. In this case, the $x$ must be integrable, so at a first cut, we take $x \in L^1[0,1]$.

Your intuition is correct, and we can proceed directly or by using standard techniques such as Lagrange multipliers.

It is generally more difficult with such problems to assert the existence of
extrema. In this particular example we can appeal to convexity (through Jensen's inequality) to show that
the average is the extremising value.

Given that we know that an $\max$ exists, we can use Lagrange multipliers to
compute a solution. One version of the theorem requires that the constraint function $g$ be surjective.

The problem is (slightly relaxed)
$\min \{ f(x) | g(x) = 0 \}$ where $x \in L^1[0,1]$, $f(x) = \int f \circ x$,
and $g(x) = \int x$. We see that $g$ is surjective. It is straightforward to compute
${\partial f(x) \over \partial x}h = \int {\partial f(x(t)) \over \partial x} h(t) dt$ and ${\partial g(x) \over \partial x}h = \int h(t) dt$
and it is straightforward to check that derivatives are continuous.

Then at a $\max$, say $x^*$,  there exists a multiplier $\lambda$ such that
${\partial f(x^*) \over \partial x} + \lambda {\partial g(x^*) \over \partial x} = 0$.

This reduces to ${\partial f(x^*(t)) \over \partial x} + \lambda  = 0$ for ae. $t$. Since $f$ is strictly monotonic, we conclude that there is some constant
$c$ such that $x^*(t) = c$ for ae. $t$  and from $g(x^*) = X$ we get $c= X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you also please tell me: (1) What is this type of problem generally called? (2) Do you know of any theorems such as Kuhn-Tucker that would declare under which conditions the Lagrangian heuristics result in (a.e.) necessary conditions? I feel like I can jury-rig a proof in this case by reformulating this as an optimal control problem and using Pontryagin's Maximum Principle, but I would like to know the more general theorem when I cannot immediately turn the constraint into a differential equation.

Comment: I am not sure there is a general name, I suppose optimal control would be reasonable. I am no expert in this area. The Lagrange multiplier theorem is not a heuristic, it does provide necessary conditions (perhaps I missed your point?). (Note that Pontryagin's maximum principle is pretty big guns!) Showing that a solution exists is often a significant problem.

Comment: The Lagrange multiplier method delivers necessary conditions under certain assumptions regarding the problem. If I were choosing $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$, I would have used the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem to claim that the first order conditions with respect to x were necessary conditions for a solution. For this problem, I do not know which theorem I can rely on, which is my main problem.

Comment: There are a variety of Lagrange multiplier theorems set in banach space.

Comment: "Lagrange multipliers on Banach spaces" -- this is exactly what I was looking for! Since the space of continuous functions over an interval with $L^p$ norm is a Banach space, this would definitely resolve my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need any of those fancy stuff here: the objective is a convex combination of function $f$ evaluated at infinite number of points. By Jensen’s inequality and due to concavity of f, the convex combination of f is less than f of the convex combination which is $X$ by the constraint. So the optimal value is less than X and is attainable too.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. What I want to learn about is the theorem that works for a more general case. For instance, consider the objective function $\int_{i=0}^1 a(i) f(x(i)) di$ with some $a:\mathbb{R}^{++}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{++}$. The necessary conditions in this case would be $a(i) f'(x(i)) = \lambda, \forall i \in [0,1]$ almost everywhere. I thought a little more about the problem, and I guess one could formulate it as an optimal control problem by defining a state variable such that the last constraint works.